# android background process not working

Tags: android, mysql

i am trying to insert value into a mysql database in android.please check the code snippet below.my code does not enter "protected string do in background".i can see the progress bar and then the app stops working i.e after entering do in background. please help

```
public class GcmServer extends Activity {


 void showToast(CharSequence msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
 private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.1.4/android/insert_records.php";
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
 regId = getIntent().getStringExtra("REGID");
 userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER");
 new CreateNewProduct().execute();
```

}
// createNewproduct class

```
 class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
      {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(GcmServer.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
        }

            /**
             * Creating product
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) 
        {


                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regId));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", userName));


                // getting JSON Object
                // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                        "POST", params);

                // check log cat fro response
                Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                // check for success tag
                try {
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully created product
                        showToast("inserted");

                    } else {
                        showToast("not inserted");
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once done
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }
```

// log cat
            01-16 12:01:36.921: E/JSON Parser(2029): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value (ViewRootImpl.java:345)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:239)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at com.example.gcmclientapp.GcmServer$CreateNewProduct.onPreExecute(GcmServer.java:212)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at com.example.gcmclientapp.GcmServer.onCreate(GcmServer.java:99)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-16 12:01:37.393: E/WindowManager(2029):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: Post the stacktrace and probably the rest of your class or at least the rest of `doInBackground()`

Comment: since my code is very long.i have posted all the relevent stuff here.please have a look and help me out :(

Comment: added logcat as well

Comment: The application is not able to connect to `http://192.168.1.4/android/insert_records.php`.

Comment: my localhost is working, i can run all other php programs :(

Comment: i have my php program on the localhost.is this line write to connect to it?http://192.168.1.4/android/insert_records.php

Comment: now m not getting connection failure error. but why is this giving error error occured while executing background process?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the error!!!
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.4 (port 80): connect failed:

probably your mysql connection not working. You can first make a ping request to check the server is found or not than you can make sure about your mysql connection properties.

Comment: i resolved the connection error.now its saying that error occured while executing background process

Comment: I think the problem is on new CreateNewProduct().execute(); as you have the CreateNewProduct with arguments. Calling the asynctask task not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are instantiating the AsyncTask "CreateNewProduct", (I don't see the this code posted) it should probably look like this:

```
CreateNewProduct createNewProduct = new CreateNewProduct(productString1, productString2... etc);
createNewProduct.execute();
```

Then it will actually run.  Pass in the productString variables if you plan to use them.

Without seeing the rest of the relevant code (the CreateNewProduct instantiation, and the rest of the AsyncTask code you wrote, and anything else related), I'm not sure what else would help -- but if you post more, I will certainly attempt to provide further assistance!  :)

Comment: dear sir,i have added the relevent stuff, can you please have a look now?